# Soundcloud, how to remove this huge orange bar?

Tags: button, iframe, embed, soundcloud

There is one year , I put on my site a Soundcloud Player in "embed mode" in an iframe. No problem. But for some time, it looks like this only on tablets and smartphone (see my attachment) . My iframe code is pretty standard . Why it displays this, and more importantly, how I remove the two orange and brown buttons ?

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//soundcloud.com/dj-loranbzh/dj-loran-set-summer-2014"></iframe>
```

[image]

Comment: I got the same issue.. did you manage to find a solution?